# Powershell Beginner Scripting

Tags: powershell

I want to write a script such that if the value is less than  ...then color is red, if value = ...then color is yellow and if the value is greater than ...then color is dark magenta. I am just experimenting with powershell.

I am a Data Science student, don't know any powershell scripting, just want to have some fun.

Comment: Well, the good news is, there are MANY online resources that can be Googled. Here's one example: https://www.hexnode.com/blogs/the-beginners-guide-to-powershell-scripting/

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why no images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) - [format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) - [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) - [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: What you are after is a simple day one hour one PS task. PS ```Comparison OPerators``` and ```Write-Host -Foegroundcolor``` in the help files get you there. Please dig at these: ['Youtube beginning PowerShell'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27beginnng+powershell%27) - [PowerShell in a month of lunches](https://www.amazon.com/Learn-PowerShell-Month-Lunches-Fourth-ebook/dp/B09XBTPJ3S/ref=sr_1_5?crid=220BYXN152KDC&keywords=powershell+month+of+lunches&qid=1668368076&sprefix=powershell+month+of+lunches%2Caps%2C146&sr=8-5) - ['TutorialSport.com PowerShell](Powershell Tutorial)

Comment: Thanks @postanote , I'll get right to it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your request, I think this PowerShell code should work:

```
$random = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 20  
if ($random -lt 15) {
    write-host "Number ist $random" -ForegroundColor Red
}

elseif ($random -eq 15) {
    write-host "Number ist $random" -ForegroundColor Green
}

elseif ($random -gt 15) {
    write-host "Number ist $random" -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I combined both of you guys code and it's working as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

Simple q&d  (quick and dirty)...

```
14, 15 | 
ForEach-Object {
    If ($PSItem -eq 15)
    {Write-Host "$($PSItem) is a match" -ForegroundColor Red}
    Else
    {Write-Warning -Message "$($PSItem) is not yet a match"}
}

# Results
<#
WARNING:  is not yet a match
15 is a match
#>
```

Comment: Thanks and just like any other if else, I can add the magenta condition as well, right?

Comment: No worries.  Yeppers, you can add any of the OS default colors ```[System.Enum]``` and ```[enum]::GetValues([System.ConsoleColor]``` you choose. Yet, for any other color values, you'd have to go deeper. In the PS shells, ***powershell.exe, pwsh.exe, and the Windows Terminal***, you can be more creative with colors . Also dig at ```$HOST.UI.RawUI``` properties. There are modules via the mspowershellgalley.com you can use as well. Ihn PowerShell just do this,  ```Find-Module -Name '*color*'```.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another version.  My console wasn't allowing DarkMagenta to show, so used Magenta instead, but mostly what you are describing.  Not everything in the script is necessary, such as the very first `[int]`, so do some experimenting to see what does, and does not, work.

```
[int]$InputValue = [int](Read-Host -Prompt "Enter a number")
Write-Host "Value is: [" -NoNewLine
Write-Host "$InputValue" -NoNewLine -ForegroundColor gray -BackgroundColor $(if($InputValue -lt 15){[ConsoleColor]::Red}elseif($InputValue -eq 15){[ConsoleColor]::Yellow}else{[ConsoleColor]::Magenta})
Write-Host "]"
```